# Flexbox - Horizontally aligning vertical text

Tags: html, css, sass, flexbox

So I'm using a flexbox to hold these elements:

[image]

It looks something like that. Though as you can tell, I'm having difficulty in horizontally centering the text.

I'm rotating the text vertically 90 degrees and the transform origin is to the left.

```
.containers {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  display:flex; 
}
.selections {
  width:100/6 *100%;
  height:100%;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  line-height: 100%;
  filter:brightness(60%) grayscale(30%);
  transition: .3s filter ease-in-out;
  color:#DDD;
  h2 {
    position:absolute;
    margin:0 auto;
    top:50%;
    transform: rotate(90deg) translateX(-50%);
    transform-origin: left;
  }
}
```

I should probably include the HTML.

```
<div class="containers">
<div class="selections one"> <h2> BOWL </h2> </div>
<div class="selections two"> <h2> GOBLET </h2> </div>
<div class="selections three"> <h2> GUPPY BOX </h2> </div>
<div class="selections four"> <h2> LAMP </h2> </div>
<div class="selections five"> <h2> LAMINATED BOWL </h2> </div>
<div class="selections six"> <h2> OVENSTICK  </h2> </div>
<div class="selections seven"> <h2> WALRUS TOY </h2> </div>
<div class="selections eight"> <h2> WHISTLE </h2> </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That code doesn't replicate what you see in the picture. Please create a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with what you have so far. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bgMyag

Comment: Oh uh. http://codepen.io/aphsai/pen/mRLYXe 
This should probably work? But the colour is not showing up...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing `transform-origin` on the h2 to center, removing the `translateX()`, and add `display: flex; justify-content: center;` to the parent `.selections`.

```css
.containers {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.selections {
  width: 16.66667%;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 100%;
  filter: brightness(60%) grayscale(30%);
  transition: .3s filter ease-in-out;
  color: #DDD;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.selections h2 {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0 auto;
  top: 50%;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform-origin: center;
}

.one {
  background-color: #aa0000;
}

.one:hover {
  filter: brightness(90%) grayscale(10%);
}

.two {
  background-color: #b21900;
}

.two:hover {
  filter: brightness(90%) grayscale(10%);
}

.three {
  background-color: #bd3d00;
}

.three:hover {
  filter: brightness(90%) grayscale(10%);
}

.four {
  background-color: #cb6600;
}

.four:hover {
  filter: brightness(90%) grayscale(10%);
}

.five {
  background-color: #da9300;
}

.five:hover {
  filter: brightness(90%) grayscale(10%);
}

.six {
  background-color: #e7bd00;
}

.six:hover {
  filter: brightness(90%) grayscale(10%);
}

.seven {
  background-color: #f2e200;
}

.seven:hover {
  filter: brightness(90%) grayscale(10%);
}

.eight {
  background-color: #fbfd00;
}

.eight:hover {
  filter: brightness(90%) grayscale(10%);
}
```

```html
<div class="containers">
  <div class="selections one">
    <h2> BOWL </h2> </div>
  <div class="selections two">
    <h2> GOBLET </h2> </div>
  <div class="selections three">
    <h2> GUPPY BOX </h2> </div>
  <div class="selections four">
    <h2> LAMP </h2> </div>
  <div class="selections five">
    <h2> LAMINATED BOWL </h2> </div>
  <div class="selections six">
    <h2> OVENSTICK  </h2> </div>
  <div class="selections seven">
    <h2> WALRUS TOY </h2> </div>
  <div class="selections eight">
    <h2> WHISTLE </h2> </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @SetsunaF.Seiei sweet, no problem.